# Does this have a Euler circuit or a Euler path?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Not quite sure on how to find the Euler path in here. If there's even one.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Do you know a relation between existence of such paths and degrees of vertices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to draw this picture without lifting the pen?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595157/is-it-possible-to-draw-this-picture-without-lifting-the-pen)

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard method for checking whether a simple connected graph has an Eulerian Circuit. A simple connected graph has an Eulerian circuit iff the degree of every vertex is even. Then, you can just go ahead and on such a small graph construct one. For example, ABFECDEGCBGFA.

However, all you need for an Eulerian path is that at least n-2 vertices have even degree where n is the number of vertices in your graph. Then , you start at a vertex with odd degree and end at one as well.